# The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (JPanel)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Main implements ActionListener{
    JButton button;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        redPanel.setBounds(0,250,250,250);
        redPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        bluePanel.setBounds(250,250,250,250);
        bluePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
        greenPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        greenPanel.setBounds(0,0,500,250);
        greenPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(750, 750);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        redPanel.add(label);
        redPanel.add(button);
        frame.add(redPanel);
        frame.add(bluePanel);
        frame.add(greenPanel);
        button.setBounds(0,250,250,250);
        button.addActionListener(redPanel);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == button) {
            System.out.print("ahahah");
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to add a fully functioning button inside the main class

i had the error:The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (JPanel)

(I tried putting JPanel as an argument)

```
button.addActionListener(redPanel);
```

Comment: A JPanel is not an ActionListener. However, you could let your panel implement that interface too. Your Main class is an ActionListener too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register a `java.awt.Component` (which JPanel is) as an `ActionListener` of `JButton`. Instead you should use one of the appropriate listeners listed here, to register one onto the `JPanel`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html

You should do:

```
button.addActionListener(new Main());
```

but it would be better if you create a new class for the `ActionListener` and implement the interface there, and then in the main method use the constructor of your own listener.

And always read the documentation ;)

Comment: it has no errors (thankfully) but its not displaying the message in the console

Comment: That is curious, can you show us the whole code (update your question)? So far, you do not have debugged it, because the only way it is not displayed, is that the listener is not triggered.